# Is it possible to embed a base64 image with CFMailParam?

Tags: coldfusion, base64

I'm working on an app that creates customized images based on user inputs using canvas and I was wondering if it was possible to allow users to email themselves a copy of the final product in base64 or if I would have to convert it to `.jpg` or `.png` and then embed it as that.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and how did it turn out?

Comment: I tried using an <img> tag and it outputted the whole string ('<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABOAAAAIiCAYAAAB...') and marked the email as spam.

Comment: @JackPilowsky This link might be useful for you.
https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Comment: @JackPilowsky - Code belongs in the question for better visibility. Not everyone reads the  comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest converting the Base64 to an image, writing to disk, and using cfmailparam to attach/inline it as well as automatically remove it from disk.

I have had nothing but issues trying to directly inline/attach base64 images to emails using cfmail. I have had partial success converting the base64 to an image object (using ImageReadBase64()) and then using the image object as the value of the cfmailparam content attribute and ommitting the file attribute, however the image comes through with inverted colors oddly enough.

On to some example code...

```
<cfsavecontent variable="mailContent">
...
<img src="cid:signature">
...
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset sigImage = ImageReadBase64(SIGNATURE_IMAGE_BASE64)> 
<cfimage source="#sigImage#" destination="tmpSigImage.png" action="write" overwrite="true">

<cfmail ...>
#mailContent#
<cfmailparam
    file="#ExpandPath('./tmpSigImage.png')#"
    contentid="signature"
    disposition="inline"
    remove="yes"
    />
</cfmail>
```

Comment: To whoever gave me an upvote and made my rep 666, well done :P. Now I just need to gain an up or down vote to free myself from this curse.